# How to set the default selected component

Tags: java, select, jframe, components

I am creating a Java Text Editor, and I don't want people to have to click on the text area to type. I have multiple buttons at the top of the screen, the top left most one is automatically selected. Is there any way to automatically select the text area component? Also, do I need to share my code or can I just use an example code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JTextArea area =...;

SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      area.requestFocus();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to select the text in the TextArea, use the method selectAll()